# Border color of combox does not change - Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-8

The border does not change.
I don't have a global/local style applied, only one for fontSize. 
App.xaml is empty..no styles there.

If have also added a combobox to a plain window and set the border color,
also with no luck???

**So where could it be overriden?**

The combobox sits in window root, it has no container like Grid,StackPanel,etc.

The window:

```
<Window x:Name="XyzWindow" x:Class="Xyz.Final" Title="MyTitle"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:wc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hasng"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel,IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="350" Width="650" ResizeMode="NoResize" AutomationProperties.Name="wHashScreen" 
        Icon="/xyz;component/IMG/thumbprint.png" FontWeight="Bold" UseLayoutRounding="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show an image? **The border does not change** means the border does not change on click?

Comment: it does never change, even in a fresh wpf project... it's OS related,but how t override it?

Comment: I had faced similar issues with other controls in Win8. I will post a workaround that I followed as an answer. Please do check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the ComboBox' BorderBrush property you'll need to [edit the Template](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24240.changing-the-background-color-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8.aspx) and change the Binding in the ToggleButton ControlTemplate

```
BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"
```

to

```
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

Comment: Yes, I read the article. But how can I override the borderbrush color from inside my window xaml using triggers. I know I can change it directly in the generated template, but this is hard coded...

Comment: Or atleast how to override it using a custom style under window.resources.

Comment: @Legends I couldn't find a way using styles or overriding resources. Actually it's the other way around, if you change the Binding to TemplateBinding it will no longer be hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues while loading my application on `Windows 8`, which used to work fine on `Windows 10` and `Windows 7`.

This is a workaround I have done for such applications which needed to be run on `Win8`. I have added a border around the control and it used to display it without any issues in Windows8. I hope this helps in your case too.

```
<Border Name="ComboBoxBorder" BorderThickness="1.5" BorderBrush="Red">
    <ComboBox Name="ComBoxName"  Width="80" Height="45">
        <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Border>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought of a way of doing it. I will upvote it, but not mark it as an answer as I am looking for a way to override the OS style if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this workaround is only needed on Windows 8**

In addition two Funk's answer:

1.) Put a combobox on the Ui
--> right-click--> Edit template-> Edit a copy 
     --> Choose application --> Ok(ComboBoxStyleNew)

2.) [Copied from Funk's answer:]
Change the BorderBrush property of

```
BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"
```

to (this makes the borderbrush property overridable)

```
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

here a little excerpt:

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

In my case I use MultiDataTriggers, to change the border color of the combobox dynamically.
ComboBoxStyleNew is the name/key of the control template resource we created in step 1.
ComboBoxTemplate is the key of the combobox template.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}">
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyleNew}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition 
                        Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Button1MouseDetector}" 
                        Value="MouseOver" 
                        />
                    <Condition 
                        Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=button1}" 
                        Value="False" 
                        />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>                     
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Upvote for the elaborate answer. Will give it a try next time there is a Win8 issue like this.